# regex extracting mac address into string

Tags: python, regex, macos

I'm trying to use regex to extract a MAC address from a string. The regex that I've used should work.

`raw_mac_string` returns a `ether <mac_address>`

What I'm trying to do is get `original_mac` to extract the `<mac_address>` from `raw_mac_string`.

`original_mac` when run, keeps giving error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Thanks for the help

I guess my question is, how can I extract the MAC address from a string that contains other text as well?

```
#get original mac address
    global original_mac
    raw_mac_string = subprocess.check_output('ifconfig en0 | grep ether | awk "{print $2}"', shell=True)
    print "raw_mac"+raw_mac_string
    original_mac = re.match(r"/^(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}$/", raw_mac_string).group()
```

Comment: Your regexp only matches if the whole string is the MAC address. If `raw_mac_string` is `ether <mac address>`, it won't match because of `ether` at the beginning.

Comment: So how can I change my regex so that it skips the words that aint the MAC address?

Comment: Use a lookbehind that matches `^ether ` but doesn't include it in the match.